# Centos TFTP boot server without a dhcpd server

Tags: linux, centos, router, dhcp, tftp

Good Day,

I want to ask the comunity if it is possible to setup a TFTP boot server without running a local dhcpd server on the local box? The setup currently looks like this?

What is currently happening (2 dhcpd servers clashing) router (with dhcpd) -----> centos tftp boot server (dhcpd) ----> client desktop

What is needed: router (with dhcpd) -----> centos tftp boot server ----> client desktop

Any help / suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible although it may or may not work with your (unspecified) equipment.

You need to tell the router(with dhcpd) to provide the address of the tftp server and the file name to request. How you do this is very much dependant on router(with dhcpd).

For example pfsense

[image: PFsense DHCP tftp config]

Other router(with dhcpd) will be different.

Comment: I have a ASUS dsl router. It does not have such options. I would have to assume that it would be better to disable the router's dhcp and use the OS's dhcp rather?

Comment: @QXT: I guess so.

Answer (score 2):

As answer 1, you might just disable dhcp on your router and move that role to a configurable box, like your CentOS Server

A simple sample config might be (dhcpd.conf):

```
subnet 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
     option domain-name-servers 192.168.2.1, 8.8.8.8;
     option routers 192.168.2.1;
     range 192.168.2.20 192.168.2.100;
     authoritative;
}
```

- Network: 192.168.2.0/24
- Gateway: 192.168.2.1
- DNS: 192.168.2.1 (your gateway, typical small router setup), 8.8.8.8 (google dns, should not be necessary as your router should push unknown dns requests to its parent dns server, mostly ISP)
- IP-Range: 20-100 (might be smaller or larger, adjust for your needs)

As you see, you have to adjust your IPs (net, gateway, dns).

See this link for further informations: http://www.daemon-systems.org/man/dhcpd.conf.5.html